# Blend 5 Preview designer crashes after VS rebuild

Tags: silverlight, parsing, exception, blend, xamlparseexception

I am working on a big silverlight project, and have problems editing it in Blend;
Initially, Blend starts properly, designer shows the controls, etc.

However, unexpectedly, after parallel work in VisualStudio and at least one rebuild, I get this exception

```
XamlParseException: [Line: 0 Position 0]

StackTrace
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size     availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single   inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Edit: Is it maybe because of TFS?

Comment: Were you hand-editing XAML in Visual Studio as well as your code?

Comment: No, most of the time it crashes while still working in Blend